# Will this equation with $\sin$ and $\arcsin$ cancel?

Tags: trigonometry

It can be said that $\arcsin(\sin(x))= x$ are inverses if $x \lt 2\pi$.

Can it also be generalized so that $\arcsin(\sin(d\cdot x))= d\cdot x$ if $x \lt 2\pi\cdot d$ for a constant $d$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrect about the domain of arcsine. Arcsine has a domain of values $y$ where $-1 \leq y \leq 1$, which means if we take $y = \sin(x)$ our values of $x$ are restricted by $-\pi/2 \leq x \leq \pi/2$. So as long as your constant $d$ is such that $zd = x$ where $x \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ then we do know $\arcsin(\sin(dz)) = dz$. To say that this idea is "generalized" is also not true though, since it requires us to introduce a constant $d$ in addition to our variable $x$. The true generalization is that $\arcsin(\sin(x)) = x$ for $x \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. It is trivial that we can write $x$ as a product of another variable and a constant. Choose any $c \neq 0$ and set $z = \frac{x}{c}$ to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

$\arcsin$ is the invese function of $\sin x$ only if $x$ is restricted to the range $[-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2]$.  It is true that $\arcsin (\sin (d\cdot x))=d\cdot x$ for $-\frac \pi 2\le d\cdot x \le\frac \pi 2$